# Change hourly jquery timer to daily

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi everybody I’ve tried (and failed) to change this simple jquery code to countdown 24 hours instead of the current 1 hour.  I have a function called `getMinutesUntilNextHour()` that should calculate and display the 24 hour countdown:

```
function getMinutesUntilNextHour() { 

    var now = new Date();
    var mins = now.getMinutes();
    var secs = now.getSeconds();
    var cur_mins = 60 - mins; 
    var cur_secs = 60 - secs;

    if (cur_secs == 60) {
        cur_mins = cur_mins;
        cur_secs = 0;
    } else {
        cur_mins = cur_mins - 1;
    }

    if(secs > 50){
         var response = (cur_mins) + ":0" + (cur_secs);
    } else if(cur_secs == 0) {
         var response = (cur_mins) + ":00";
    } else {
        var response = (cur_mins) + ":" + (cur_secs);
    }
    jQuery('#time_till_hour').text(function(){
        return response; 
    });
    setTimeout(getMinutesUntilNextHour, 1000);
}

getMinutesUntilNextHour();
```

I added `now.getHours()` then `cur_hours = 24 - hours` but it doesn’t display correctly. Should I add something to if current `hours = 0` section?

Thanks in advance for any help you may be able to offer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could adjust and simplify your `getMinutesUntilNextHour()` function in the following way:

```js
function getMinutesUntilNextHour() { 
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    var mins = now.getMinutes();
    var secs = now.getSeconds();
    
    // Compute time remaining per unit
    var cur_hours = 23 - hours; 
    var cur_mins = 60 - mins; 
    var cur_secs = 60 - secs;
    
    // Correct zero padding of hours if needed
    if(cur_hours < 10) {
     cur_hours = '0' + cur_hours;
    }
    
    // Correct zero padding of minutes if needed
    if(cur_mins < 10) {
     cur_mins = '0' + cur_mins;
    }
    
    // Correct zero padding of seconds if needed
    if(cur_secs < 10) {
     cur_secs = '0' + cur_secs;
    }
    
    // Format the countdown string
    var response = cur_hours + ':' + cur_mins + ':' + cur_secs;
    
    jQuery('#time_till_hour').text(response);
    setTimeout(getMinutesUntilNextHour, 1000);
}

getMinutesUntilNextHour();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time_till_hour">
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Comment: Going one step further, is there a way to have the 24 hour count down the same no matter what time zone you’re in? As I understand it will display a different time depending on which country you are in. Can we say 00:00 UTC for example?

Comment: @Zach89 you're welcome - glad I could help! If this answer has been of use to you, please consider accepting :-)

Comment: @Zach89 yes, regarding utc, you can achieve this by using the "UTC" method equivalents that the Date object provides. So, replace `now.getHours()` with `now.getUTCHours()`, `now.getMinutes()` with `now.getUTCMinutes()`, and so on